# Continuity of expected payoff from a diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Fix a discount rate $r>0$, and let $m,v,f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded measurable functions of locally bounded variation, with $v$ globally bounded below by some strictly positive constant i.e. $v(x) > c > 0$

Given a standard Brownian motion B and a starting value x, I know the SDE
$dX_t = m(X_t) dt + v(X_t) dB_t$
has a unique strong solution with $X_0 = x$.

Let 
$U(x):= E [ \int_0^\infty re^{-rt} f(X_t) dt | X_0=x]$, a well-defined number for each $x.$

Question: 
How nice is U guaranteed to be, without imposing further conditions on m,v,f? [In particular, I don't want to assume any of them to be continuous. If further boundedness-type conditions help, I'm more okay imposing those.]
Is U guaranteed to be continuous? Differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a partial answer addressing the continuity: $U$ is continuous, even uniformly continuous. Below is the idea.

Denote $\tau_x^y = \inf\{ t\ge 0: X_t = y\,|\, X_0 = x\}$, then $\tau_x^y<\infty$ a.s. in view of the uniform non-degeneracy of $v$ and boundedness of $m$, so, using the strong Markov property, $$U(x) = rE\left[\int_0^{\tau_x^y} e^{-rs}f(X_t)dt \,\Big|\, X_0=x\right] + E\big[e^{-r\tau_x^y}\big]U(y).$$
The first term converges to $0$ uniformly as $|y-x|\to 0$ in view of the uniform non-degeneracy of $v$ and boundedness of $m$. For the same reason, $E\big[e^{-r\tau_x^y}\big]\to 1$ uniformly.

Update: $U'$ is in general discontinuous. Start by noting that we expect $U$ to solve equation $$rU - \mathcal A U - f = 0,\tag{1}$$ where $\mathcal A$ is the generator of $X$, at least in some weak sense. Then it is already clear that $U'$ or $U''$ must be discontinuous in the point where $f$, $m$ or $v$ are discontinuous.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This is extremely useful. A quick question before I fully digest your answer. What exactly is uniform degeneracy?

Comment: @Aditiya, uniforn non-degeneracy, sorry. This is $v(x) > c > 0$.

Comment: Brilliant. This is the intuition I too had. Your reply is extremely useful. Sorry to bug you more but since I didn't know that $E(e^{-r \tau^y_x}) \rightarrow 1$ I tried to prove it myself. My proof is very complicated as it involves time change of the stochastic integral. The reason why I have to do it is because $v(x)$ is a function of $x$ and not a constant. So I was wondering if you had an easy proof of this, seemingly obvious, claim.

Comment: @Aditiya, this is a standard fact about one-dimensional diffusions, see Section 4.7 in Ikeda-Watanabe or Ito-McKean (here can't say where exactly as I don't have the book at hand). But yes, you can change the time to get a Wiener process + bounded drift, and here this is just the consequence of ILL. And don't hesitate to ask, I will be glad to help (although I am not a great specialist in diffusions).

Comment: Thanks. The "problem" with Ito-McKean, from what I see, is that most of the work on diffusion assumes continuous drift and volatility. Part of the reason, I guess, they do that is because having a strong solution could be an issue otherwise for the associated SDE. In my case, my starting point is that I know that I have a strong solution to the SDE despite the coefficients not being continuous. But I also know they're bounded the way I said. So I am not able to find the exact result I can readily use (which I would like) that'll tell me that $E(e^{-r\tau^y_x}) \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: One more question. By ILL do you mean, "Iterated law of logarithms"?

Comment: @Aditiya, another typo sorry, should be LIL, the law of iterated logarithm. I believe that most of those results work for BV coefficients as well. If you are not convinced (or you find the time change too complicated), you can try to argue the use of the Lamperti transform $Y = F(X)$ with $F = \int v(x)^{-1} dx$. (Here was some rubbish, sorry.)

Comment: @Aditiya, just to be clear, some intuition why the convergence of $\tau_x^y$ to $0$ is "obvious". Let for definiteness $x>y$. Then the process $X$ starting from $x$ will reach $y$ sooner than $cW_t + x - at$, where $a = \sup |m|$, since it has a stronger drift towards $y$ and a stronger diffusion.

Comment: @ zhoraster - I see. One more question though. In your example on the discontinuity of U', I don't understand how you get $g'(0+)\sigma_1 = g'(0-)\sigma_2$. The generator with $m=0$ will involve only the second derivatives of $g$. When $m\neq 0 $ the first derivatives will show up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, in any case, I think $U$ will satisfy the equation you write at any point $x$ only if $U$ is $C^2$ at the point $x$. The way I understand, all bets are off if it's not $C^2$. So that will prevent you from making any claim about the first derivative from what I understand.

Comment: @Aditiya, the reason is that to compute the second derivative, you must first compute the first. I've added an explanation. Hope it will be clear now.

Comment: @zhoraster Hi, I doubt your example that $U’$ can be discontinuous. It is well-known that the payoff is $C^1$ on the region where the volatility is bounded away from zero. You can assume $f=0$ and then $U$ can be calculated explicitly for your process, and is differentiable at 0.

Comment: @JoeLi, you are probably right. Don't know why I wrote that. The jump in the first derivative for the domain of generator corresponds to a singular drift.

Comment: @zhorster What do you mean by singular drift?

Comment: @zhoraster Actually using green function the payoff can be expressed as an integral of the flow, with density being the green function. Then you can use Fubini to take derivative and get payoff is once differentiable. It is twice differentiable if everything is continuous.

Comment: @JoeLi, I mean equations like $dX_t = a\delta_0 (X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dW_t$, where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac delta function. E.g. the skew Brownian motion is a solution to such equation.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you for the quick response! It is really helpful.

Comment: @JoeLi, thank *you* for spotting the mistake. I've removed the incorrect part of the answer.